# Checking for changes in a given form before unload/leave page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, onbeforeunload

I have forms with about 100 input fields each (textbox, textarea, radio, checkbox, file, etc).
When the user leaves the page I need to know if some field has been modified in order to run an autosave routine.

1.- Set `form_has_been_modified` when any field change:

```
var form_has_been_modified = 0;
$("form[id^='my_form']").each(function(){
    $(":input", this).live("change", function() {
        form_has_been_modified = 1;
    });
});
```

2.- Warn user if some field was changed:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if ( ! form_has_been_modified){
        return;
    }

    var message = "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.";

    var e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = message;
    }

    // For Safari
    return message;
};
```

**Questions**:

a.- Could this code (part 1) make too much slow the browser's user?

b.- The previous code is working very well. But in `textbox/textarea` input types the `change` event only occur when elements loses focus. So for example this code does not protect against `reload page` actions. There exists another better handler instead `change` to solve this deficiency?

Comment: Checkout this https://github.com/acvwilson/dirty_form/wiki plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `keyup`, which might be close enough, although you could get some false positives.

Also, with `.on()` you can replace your `.each()` loop with a single call (and `.live()` had been deprecated in 1.7+ anyway):

```
$("form[id^='my_form']").on("change keyup", ":input", function() {
     form_has_been_modified = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```
$('#form').data('serialize',$('#form').serialize());
  // On load save form current state

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
    if($('#form').serialize()!=$('#form').data('serialize'))return true;
    else e=null;
    // i.e; if form state change show box not.
});
```

You can Google JQuery Form Serialize function, this will collect all form inputs and save it in array.  I guess this explain is enough :)

Comment: I like this approach better

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you might want to add `return false;` to break the loop once a changed form field is found ... so you don't bother checking all the rest of the fields unnecessarily.  That's assuming, of course, that you only need to know if *any* field has changed, not a list of *all* that have been changed.  Given that, if field #2 is changed, why take the time to check all remaining 98 fields.

Comment: The first loop is only applying the change handlers, not actually checking for changes.  Each handler will only be called when that element changes value.  Also, returning `false` inside of a `.each()` loop only moves to the next iteration of `.each()`, it does not actually end the loop.

Comment: The equivalent to what you are suggesting in terms of handlers would be to use `.one()` instead of `.on()` when applying a delegated handler, such as the one in my answer.